# Timeseries OLS Coefficient Interpretation - Log Sum Transformation

Tags: regression, time-series, interpretation, regression-coefficients

This should be straightforward and I apologize in advance but for some reason, a colleague and I are in disagreement over the interpretation of some regression coefficients. Suppose we have a time-series regression given by:

$Y_t = \beta_0 + \beta_1 Y_{t-1}$

Per the standard interpretation, if $\beta_1 = 0.1$ for example, a 1 unit increase in $Y_{t-1}$ is associated with a 0.1 increase in $Y_t$.

How would this interpretation change if $Y$ is defined as the log of the sum of two other variables such that $Y_t = log(X_{1,t} + X_{2,t})$ ? What can $\beta_1 = 0.1$ tell us about $X_{1,t} + X_{2,t}$ ?

My current understanding is that if the sum of $X_{1,t-1} + X_{2,t-1}$ increased by 1%, $X_{1,t} + X_{2,t}$ would increase by 0.1%. Is it accurate to use this log-log interpretation on a time-series regression?

Comment: Your notation suggests you are working with a time series (where $t=1,2,3,\ldots$) rather than a "simple regression" (where there are multiple observations of the ordered pair $(Y_{t-1},Y_t)$ for a *fixed* $t.$)  Which is it really?

Comment: @whuber my apologies, you are correct. As the notation indicates this is a time series regression. How does this change the interpretation of the coeffficients?

Comment: I suggest you incorporate that comment into your question and tag it with [tag:time-series].  That ought to attract useful answers.

Comment: After re-reading your edited post, I have to wonder what you're trying to get at, because the glib (but perfectly correct and useful) answer is "it tells you exactly the same thing it would tell you about $\exp(Y_t)$ -- namely, $X_{1,t}+X_{2,t}$ is the exponential of an AR(1) process with coefficient $\beta_1.$"  In particular, you haven't any hope of inferring things about the $X_{i,t}$ separately.  Could you be more specific about what "tell us" might entail?

Comment: Thank you for your comment on tagging it with time-series. I am trying to understand how $X_{1,t} + X_{2,t}$ changes when $X_{1,t-1} + X_{2,t-1}$ increases by 1 unit (or 1%). I am not very familiar with autoregressive terms, but I have also updated the question with my current interpretation – do you agree with it?